# How to playback pointcloud in rviz which was recorded using rosbag

Tags: kinect, rviz, pcl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi my friends, I am quite new to ROS and pointcloud. I am running some experiments with pointcloud using kinect.

after running `roslaunch openni_launch openni.launch` and `rosbag record /camera/depth/points` for a few seconds, i terminate the recording and get a .bag file in /bagfile.
Now i want to play back the .bag file and visualize it in rviz. Any clue how to achieve this?
Thanks a lot for your kind instruction!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/72202/how-to-playback-pointcloud-in-rviz-which-was-recorded-using-rosbag/) by [ljk](https://answers.ros.org/users/5470/ljk/) on ROS Answers with karma: 155 on 2013-08-11

Post score: 5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You'll want to set use_sim_time to true (do this BEFORE starting rviz):

```
rosparam set use_sim_time true
```

Then use rosbag, and republish the clock:

```
rosbag play name_of_bagfile.bag --clock
```

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2013-08-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 13

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ljk](https://answers.ros.org/users/5470/ljk/) on 2013-08-12**:
Thanks fergs! It works!
btw, it should be " /user_sim_time"

**Comment by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) on 2013-08-12**:
No, it should be use_sim_time, just as @fergs wrote.

**Comment by [ljk](https://answers.ros.org/users/5470/ljk/) on 2013-08-13**:
sorry~~my fault, should be "use_sim_time" or "/use_sim_time" ,both are fine

**Comment by [Battery](https://answers.ros.org/users/7016/battery/) on 2013-11-08**:
Do you mean that first 'rosparam set use_sim_time true' and then run rviz and then 'rosbag play name_of_bagfile.bag --clock'? I do the same procedure but cant play back the data. Furthermore, my rosbag record just record only 2 seconds for the kinect. How can I fix it? Thanks a lot.

**Comment by [kleinsplash](https://answers.ros.org/users/5014/kleinsplash/) on 2014-02-09**:
Yes, rosrun rviz rviz after setting param true. What I do is,run as above, quickly set the topic, then run the bag again and the topic will show as expected inside rviz. You have a bag that was recorded for 2s - dont set the time and you can record as long as you like: rosbag record -O subset /topic